# Notepadd++ plugin sqlinform for SQL formatting bright orange color background

Tags: plugins, notepad++

I am using Notepadd++ plugin sqlinform for SQL formatting
from
https://www.sqlinform.com/download-free-notepad-plugin/

It works fine but has nasty orange background after formatting

[image]

Is this some glitch?
Update: The issue is fixed by the author of the plugin. Please use the latest version.

Comment: What version of Npp? I remember (not really sure by the way) there was a bug like that in V8.4.6.

Comment: @Toto,  I am using the latest version as of today 8.4.7.  do you use sql formatter though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is now fixed with Release 6.23.2. SQLinForm now respects the change history column from N++. The new Release is available for Download from here: https://www.sqlinform.com/download-free-notepad-plugin/

[image]

Answer (score 7):

@PAS, I had the same issue. I found the fix on SQLinForm's forum. It's a new feature called "Display Change History". Settings -> Preferences -> Margins/Border/Edge -> Checkbox in the center column at the bottom.

Hope this helps!

https://forum.sqlinform.com/n-plugin/turn-off-highlighting-of-edited-lines/